# Questions with would

Tags: will-would, wh-questions

I'm practicing the use of would and I have a problem with one exercise, I have to put these words in order:  would, be, the problem, what and a question mark (?).
And now I don't know how to put them.
What is the correct answer?

1. What would the problem be?
   Or
2. What would be the problem?
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, grammatical English questions.  They also have similar meanings, with the conditional "would" acting to make the question more tentative (and so more polite) than "What is the problem?"

Comment: Ohhhh so the more appropriate is: What would the problem be? Right?

Comment: I think they are both perfectly acceptable. Equally appropriate, there may be some difference of use in context.  Perhaps if these were part of a longer structure "What would the problem be if I deleted the file"  "What would be the problem if I deleted the file."...Actually those seem to be pretty similar in meaning too.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you so much!